# The Custom UILabel can't move with touch gesture

Tags: ios, uilabel

I’m intend to customize a UILabel and put it move with touch gestures, so I created a class named CustomLabel that inherits from UILabel and achieved the following two methods for handing touch events. But, the CustomLabel can’t move anyway !  However, when I change the father class of CustomLabel with UIView, UIbutton and etc. it’s works well. So anyone who can tell me the reason about this phenomen.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
     if(!dragEnable)
     {return;}
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     beginPoint = [touch locationInView: self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if(!dragEnable)
     {return;}
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint nowPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
   float offsetX = nowPoint.x - beginPoint.x;
   float offsetY = nowPoinr.y - beginPoint.y;
   self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x+offsetX, self.center+offsetY);
}
```

I apologize if any of my questions are so basic.
Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you put a log in touchesBegan:withEvent: to see if it's called? Did you set userInteractionEnabled to YES for the label (it's NO by default for labels)?

Comment: Also worth noting: you set nowPoint to have coordinates in terms of `self`, whereas the `center` coordinates are generally in terms of the superview...

Comment: thanks very much. I forgot to set userInteractionEnabled to YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for my questions are so basic, and I have found the solution. I forgot to  set userInteractionEnabled to YES for the label object. I'm very sorry for this mistake.